# Why 'would' in this example?

Tags: will-would

In the Marvin Gaye song "I Heard It Through the Grapevine" the refrain  is:

> *Ooo I heard it through the grapevine
>
> Not much longer **would** you be mine
>
> Ooo I heard it through the grapevine
>
> And I'm just about to lose my mind*

Why not "will" instead of "would", because in this song the character is still going out with that girl? They have not broken up yet even if he thinks that it will be the end soon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Future in the past narrative](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47858/future-in-the-past-narrative)

Answer (score 2):

Because the tense of "would" describes a time that is in the *future* at the point at which he heard the words, but in the *past* by the time he gets round to reporting this hearing-of-the-words in the song.

EDIT -- the following is better in line with the timescales in the song:

"I **will** do the job in three weeks time," said your colleague to you last week.

This week you say to him, "You said you **would** do the job in three weeks time last time we spoke -- are we still on schedule for that?"

Comment: But the next  sentence în the song is ' I m about to lose my mind 'so this sentence is future and I thought the other one was also future not future in the past

Comment: @user5577 Whether the eventuality of the losing of the squeeze is future or past makes no difference on the fact that the *reported sentence* was in the past.